# Code Wont Run, Got Strange Error

Tags: java

I have got some code and it all seems to work apart from one error that appears. This stops the whole program running. Please could you have a look at the code and see what the issue is. This is a space invaders game and this is the class that contains the public static void main.

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Alien {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        /**
         * The Alien class. 
         */


            public static int ALIEN_HEIGHT = 25;
            public static int ALIEN_WIDTH = 15;

            private int leftPosition = 0;
            private int heightPosition = 0;

            private boolean hitState = false;//Whether this alien has already been shot

            private Image alienImage = null;

            SpaceInvaders spaceInvaders = null;

            /**
             *
             */
            public Alien(Image ai, SpaceInvaders si) {
                alienImage = ai;
                spaceInvaders = si;
            }

            /**
             * Returns whether ythe alien had been hit
             */
            public boolean hasBeenHit() {
                return hitState;
            }

            /**
             * Check if a shot fired hit an alien
             */
            public boolean hitAlien(int x, int y) {

                //Is the alien currently alive?
                if (hitState) {
                    //If it's alreay been shot then return false;
                    return false;
                }

                //First lets check the X range
                if ((x >= leftPosition) && (x <= (leftPosition+ALIEN_WIDTH))) {
                    //X is ok, now lets check the Y range
                    if ((y >= heightPosition) && (y <= (heightPosition+ALIEN_HEIGHT))) {
                        //We shot an alien!
                        hitState = true;
                        return true;
                    }
                } 
                return false;
            }

            /**
             * Set the position of the alien on the screen
             */
            public void setPosition(int x, int y) {
                leftPosition = x;
                heightPosition = y;
            }

            /**
             * Returns the current x position of the alien
             */
            public int getXPos() {
                return leftPosition;
            }

            /**
             * Returns the current x position of the alien
             */
            public int getYPos() {
                return heightPosition;
            }

            /**
             * Draw the image of the Alien 
             */ 
            public void drawAlien(Graphics g) {
                if (!hitState) {
                    g.setColor(Color.red);
                    g.fillRect(leftPosition, heightPosition, ALIEN_WIDTH, ALIEN_HEIGHT);
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

The error is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody

```
at Alien.main(Alien.java:3)
```

Comment: ... and that "strange" error is? ...

Comment: Please post the full text of the error message, we can't guess at it.

Comment: Sorry, how can it _[seem] to work_ of it doesn't even compile?

Comment: It means you're trying to run uncompilable code -- don't do that. First fix the compilation problem, test that it compiles first, and only then try to run it.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be mis-understanding the basics of Java syntax.  Specifically, you cannot define your class's members and methods *inside* `main()` the way you are attempting to do:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Alien {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        /**
         * The Alien class. 
         */


            public static int ALIEN_HEIGHT = 25;  // you can't put this here
            public static int ALIEN_WIDTH = 15;   // you can't put this here

            private int leftPosition = 0;         // you can't put this here
            private int heightPosition = 0;       // you can't put this here
            //etc
```

To get this to compile, you need to close `main()` and delete all the extra `}` you have at the end of your code:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Alien {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * The Alien class. 
     */
    public static int ALIEN_HEIGHT = 25;
    public static int ALIEN_WIDTH = 15;
    //etc
```

You'll also need to add some code to `main()` before your program actually does anything.

I would suggest that before you continue your current program you read some of the excellent tutorials online.  A good place to start is [The Java™ Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) on the oracle website.

Look at the **Trails Covering the Basics** section and work your way through [Getting Started](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html) and [Learning the Java Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) before doing anything else.

Comment: 1+ It looks like the OP needs to first read a Java book before trying to create a program. He appears to be just guessing at this and hoping it will somehow work, and that approach never works.